# Is it possible to fix Quick Maps layers not displaying properly when zoomed out in WGS84 in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I often want to display some global point or polygon data over a base layer, to provide some context. Quick Maps layers like OpenStreetMap are handy for this, but these layers are usually in EPSG:3857, and when I zoom out to view the full globe in EPSG:3857, the projection maps incorrectly:

[image: world map with bad transformation]

This is not a problem if zoomed in further, the transformation is applied correctly at finer scales:

[image: local map with correct transformation]

Is there something I can do to make the zoomed-out version map correctly? I know I can use a global EPSG:3857 projection, and transform my vector data instead, but that doesn't always play nice:

[image: globe with bad vector transform]

and even if it did, EPSG:4236 is a much nicer projection for a full globe view for data like this (less pole dominance).

Comment: I don't think you mean EPSG:3587 https://epsg.io/3587 ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant 3857. Will edit.

Comment: I suspect that that is not a WMS layer, it looks like a well known quick maps issue where it doesn't respect the projection of the project.

Comment: @IanTurton: yes, sorry, it's quickmaps. I thought that quickmaps used WMS. I will edit the question.